# Combine RTK query and redux for a muation scenario

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have created an api slice like this:

```
export const authSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: "auth",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: resolveApiBaseUrl(),
        prepareHeaders(headers) {
            headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            headers.set("X-XSRF-TOKEN", <string>resolveUserToken())
            return headers
        }
    }),

    endpoints(builder) {
        return {
            login: builder.mutation<GymAppResponse, Login>({
                query: (payload) => ({
                    url: "/login",
                    method: "POST",
                    body: payload
                }),
            })
       }
})

export const {
    useLoginMutation,
} = authSlice
```

I am getting the user token after login action and store it in localStorage so I can limit user access to some part of my application.

1. I am trying to use `redux toolkit` in order to interact with `userToken` and as default state for userToken I want to use localStorage value. So I dont want to write code in my component to check the localStorage and do the necessary logic. I want to use redux so when the `userToken` value updated in localStorage, Redux will automatically update the component for me using `useEffect(() => {...}, userTokenWhichRetrivedFromRedux)`.
2. I couldnt find any information on the doc for how to use `mutation` and combine it with redux toolkit! I used to use `redux-saga` which I called `redux actions` after a `success` or `fail` request/response.

Question: so I am asking all the knowledgeable fellows out there:

1. What is the best practice here?
2. Unfortunately `redux-persist` is not being actively maintained and I have to use localStorage prgramatically. Is there a package or best practice for handling data which we need to persist after an Api call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did it in a similar use case :

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
   name: "auth",
   initialState,
   reducers: {},
   extraReducers: (builder) => {
     builder
       .addMatcher(authApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled, (state, action) => {
         state.user = action.payload;
       })
       .addMatcher(authApi.endpoints.logout.matchFulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = null;
       });
   },
});
```

You can also use the [createListenerMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware) to access a state slice and provide a callback that will execute based on `matchers`

```
const authListenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware();

authListenerMiddleware.startListening({
  matcher: isAnyOf(
    authApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
    authApi.endpoints.logout.matchFulfilled
  ),
  effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
    if (action.meta.arg.endpointName === "login") {
      const user = listenerApi.getState().auth.user;
      localStorage.setItem(AUTHENTICATED_USER, JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    if (action.meta.arg.endpointName === "logout") {
      localStorage.removeItem(AUTHENTICATED_USER);
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive example, I found it easier to use `redux-persist` and I have abandoned using `localStorage` directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can find relevant examples [here in the RTK Query "examples" section](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers)

As I understand it, you want to adjust Redux state as the result of a mutation. In that case, the easiest way of doing that would be adding an `extraReducer` for the mutation fulfilled action to your slice.

As for redux-persist: That library is pretty much "finished" years ago - it does not need a lot of active maintenance to be useful, especially giving it's pluggable nature. You should be perfectly fine using that.

Comment: How Can I access other slice state inside `extraReducer`. Imagine if I want to clear some data after logout which those data are stored in another slice like `userSlice`

Comment: Is there any way to access another slice like `authSlice` and get token and inject it into `headers` section of a muation( not global for the whole `createApi`, just for a specific endpoint mutation)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you need to achieve two things:

1. Extract the token received from the login mutation and store it in a different redux slice
2. Change that value every time local storage changes

For the first part, I think you can achieve this using the [onQueryStarted utility](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted) which allows you to await for the login query to be finished and also gives you access to the dispatch function so you can perform other actions to any other slice.
**EDIT**: Now that I've seen phry's answer - yes a better solution would be matching the query fulfilled event with an extra reducer.

For the second part, this may be a little more complicated but I've gotten it to work once using the [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event). Basically, add an event listener for the local storage somewhere at the top-level of your application and then update the token every time the event is fired, i.e. using the same action as in the previous step to initially fill the local storage.